# Dividing Wordpress comments into 2 columns

Tags: html, css, wordpress, multiple-columns

I am using the WordPress comment system and would like to divide the comments into 2 columns. The most recent comments need to be at the top too, very similar to how facebook pages work.

The content on certain pages of my site is all comments - so essentially with the exception of my 'about us' page the entire content area is comments.

For your information I am using the photoria theme which is a 2 column theme but the second column is taken up by my sidebar - don't know whether this effects it or not! Hope what I am asking is clear!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple column layouts can be tricky while keeping content order accurate — i.e., keeping recent comments at the top of each columns.

**EDIT**
Assuming your markup has the same classes as the theme demo, try adding this to your CSS:

```
#commentspost { 
    overflow: hidden; /* clears floats */ 
}

.comment.odd {
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}

.comment.even {
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}
```

This will likely leave gaps due to some comments being longer than others. If that's an issue fot you then use something like the jQuery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin to take care of the additional white space that often appears between floated items.